# Prove for continuous $f$ and $g$,$f(x)<g(x)$ there exists $k$ such that $f(x)+k<g(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and for each $x$, it holds that $f(x)<g(x)$. Prove that there exists $\alpha>0$ such that for each $x$, it holds that $f(x) + \alpha <g(x)$ (Notice that $\alpha$ may not depend on $x$).

We have done a similar problem with $f(x)>0$ and proving $\alpha>0$ exists such that $f(x)>\alpha$, but I'm not exactly sure how to use supremum and infimum to solve the above version.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)+\alpha<g(x)$ iff $(g-h)(x)=g(x)-f(x)>\alpha$.

Comment: Consider the function $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)>0$.

Comment: Hint: The continuous function $g-f$ attains a minimum value on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

The comments answer the question, while the answer does not  (it attempts to prove a statement that the OP already knows how to prove). So, I'm going to record here that the statement about $f<g$ follows by applying the statement about $f>0$ to the function $g-f$.

Answer (score 0):

It only needs to use finite covering theorem for compact interval $[a, b]$.
This question ,namely :suppose $f(x)>0 ,\forall x\in [a, b]$ ,we need to proof $\exists \alpha>0 , f(x)>\alpha , \forall x\in [a, b].$\
Finite covering theorem tells us that $\exists finite\  x_i and\  \delta>0,such that\  x\in (x_i,\delta)for\ some\  x_i,x\in[a,b].$\ 
by continuity of $f(x)$,$$f(x)>\frac{f(x_i)}{2}>0,x\in (x_i,\delta)$$
when we select the minimum value of $\frac{f(x_i)}{2},here\  index \  (i) finite.$
thus ,we have solved  this question.

Comment: If fact, strictly speaking,we should use continuity of $f(x)$ firstly. then use finite covering theorem for compact interval $[a, b]$.maybe having finite $\delta_i$.but that doesn't matter.